# python: updating json response with specific value and dump the updated json resonse to a file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to parse the a big json response data and replace one value with another value. But after updating the value i am missing the below fields while writing to file.

```
    "id": "XXX",
    "tenantId": "YYYY",
    "name": "XXX",
    "version": 46,
    "description": "XXXX",
    "publishStatus": "PUBLISHED",
    "publishStatusName": "Published",
    "components": {
```

Below is a small snippet of json original response.

```
{
    "id": "XXX",
    "tenantId": "YYYY",
    "name": "XXX",
    "version": 46,
    "description": "XXXX",
    "publishStatus": "PUBLISHED",
    "publishStatusName": "Published",
    "components": {
        "XXX": {
            "data": {
                "storage": {
                    "facets": {
                        "maxValue": {
                            "type": "constant",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "value": 10000
```

Below is the code snippet.

```
  print ("Reading the blueprint data recieved:")
  with open("blueprint_response.txt", 'r') as f5:
   response_data = json.load(f5)
 #  print response_data

#parsing source machine value
   name = response_data["name"]
   print("Source machine value is given below:")
#   print(response_data["components"])
   machine_value = response_data["components"][name]["data"]["source_machine"]["facets"]["fixedValue"]["value"]["label"]
   print (machine_value)

#parsing source machine label name

   print("Source machine label is given below:")
   machine_label = response_data["components"][name]["data"]["source_machine_name"]["facets"]["fixedValue"]["value"]["value"]
   print (machine_label)

#Editing the blueprint_response file with image name

   updated_response_data = response_data

#   for i  in range(len(os_template_updated)):

   if (os_template_updated [num] == machine_value):
     print ("The OS templates are same, no change required..!!!")

   else:

     updated_response_data["components"][name]["data"]["source_machine_name"]["facets"]["fixedValue"]["value"]["value"] = os_template_updated[num]

     updated_response_data["components"][name]["data"]["source_machine"]["facets"]["fixedValue"]["value"]["label"] = os_template_updated[num]
     print updated_response_data

     with open ("blueprint_response_update.txt", "w") as f6:
      json.dump(updated_response_data, f6)
```

i want to edit the 2 values and write to new file with all the original json response intact. What i am doing wrong here?  kindly help me out please. thank in advance

Comment: well what is `num`?

Comment: i have 2 lists which contains blueprint name and template name.. 1 st blueprint name should take 1st template name. for that i am using num to fetch the corresponding value to template name list in each loop

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

`updated_response_data = response_data`

It's copying a reference to the original data. You'll want to create a new dictionary:

`updated_response_data = dict(response_data)`

should do it.

Comment: i am copying to update the copied data and dont want to update the original data. the issue is the contents inside "Components" is only writing to new file.. the data above are not at all writing.